# Flutter update screen data on resume

Tags: flutter, dart

i use the following code to redirect between screens.

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        PageRouteBuilder(
          pageBuilder: (context, animation, animation2) => Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: screen,
          ),
        ));
```

now i want it so when the user presses back, the previous screen is displayed and `initstate` recalled.(in `initstate` of previous screen i get data from server).

Comment: You can try with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`

Comment: This is not the same thing, but it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71936733/11442598

Answer (score 1):

In an `async` function, you can use `await` to wait for the user to come back from the pushed screen:

```
await Navigator.push(...);
```

But `initState` is executed only once, so I suggest using `setState` if you need to rebuild the widget, after the line above:

```
setState(() {
  // do what you need to update widget
});
```

so after the above line

Answer (score 1):

`initState` is called when the state is initialized, so it will be called only when the state is created.

You could use the then of `Navigator.push`:

```
Navigator.push(context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, animation2) => Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: screen,
    ),
  ).then((_) {
    // Your callback here
  })
)
```

Comment: your approach is very much clear. Can I call back initState();  - here ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create another function inside your first screen and get the data inside of it. then you can call this function both inside the `initState` and after `await`ing for the push command to execute.